# Fabric gives report of crash on "libc++abi.dylib" on "live app" but I couldn't replicate the crash

Tags: ios

I have implemented fabric in my application, there is a crash about 6 times on 2 devices yet on live app, but i couldn't replicate the crash my side.

Fabric says :

libc++abi.dylib

std::__terminate(void (*)())

in title and when i open the detail of this crash it only says :

Fatal Exception: std::runtime_error